# how to evaluate complex integral with half circle path?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Integration area is half circle $0 \le \arg z \le \pi$ path starts from $z=1$

So if I recall correctly circle can be described  as $z = e^{it}$

so substitute into integral gives me:

$$\int_{1}^{\pi} e^{it}\,dt$$ but calculus does nit give me exact answer which equals $2$, so it seems I do something wrong, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your circle is $\exp(ix)$ not $\exp(iz)$, with $0 \le x \le \pi$.

Hence you get
$$
\int_0^\pi e^{ix} dx
 = \int_0^\pi \cos x dx + i \int_0^\pi \sin x dx
 = 0 + i  (-\cos(\pi) - \cos(0)) = -2i.
$$

I am not sure what is the answer of 2 you are looking for, but if you are looking at area of the upper half-circle, it is $\pi/2$ not $2$.

Comment: indeed, fixed the variable,  but am I right at all?  I am not sure what I am suposed to do next

Comment: @M.Mass please see update

Comment: Ah, I see I was on the right way though, but why does the task claim "path starts from $z = 1$ I thought it denotes lower integration bound"